# File Sharing in Silverlight + WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight-3.0

I want to implement a file sharing application in Silverlight and WCF. I have a set up wherein many clients collaborate real-time on my platform.

I want to enable file sharing between them. Can anyone please suggest me few ways in implementing the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

BillKrat has an excellent article that shows how to do this..[here](http://www.global-webnet.net/blogengine/post/2010/09/12/VS2010-Project-linker.aspx)